# Set initial primal and dual values for variables pyomo

Tags: pyomo

I wan't to set initial primal and dual values in a program's variables. Is there a specific way to do this. I can see there is a initialize option in the Var object but i'm not sure how to use it in this manner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to set the value of a variable when you declare it, you can use the `initialize` keyword. E.g.,

```
model.x = Var(initialize=1.0)
```

Alternatively, you can set the `.value` attribute on a variable anytime before the solve. If you are starting with an `AbstractModel` be sure to only do this on the instance that gets returned by the `create_instance` method. Here is an example using a `ConcreteModel`:

```
model = ConcreteModel()
model.x = Var()
model.X = Var([1,2,3])

model.x.value = 5.0
model.X[1].value = 1.0
```

The NL file interface will always include the current value of all model variables in the solver input file. For other interfaces (e.g., the LP file interface), adding the keyword `warmstart=True` to the solve method will create a warmstart file that includes values of any binary or integer variables for a MIP warmstart.

To set a dual solution, you must declare a `Suffix` on your model with the name `dual`. Note that the only interface that currently supports exporting suffix information is the NL file interface (solvers that work with AMPL). However, most interfaces support importing suffix information from the solver (`dual` especially). Setting the dual value of a particular constraint might look like:

```
model = ConcreteModel()
model.dual = Suffix(direction=Suffix.IMPORT_EXPORT)
model.c = Constraint(...)
model.dual[model.c] = 1.0
```

More information about the `Suffix` component can be found in the online [documentation](https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyomo_modeling_components/Suffixes.html) for Pyomo.

Comment: @Hage Hackebell it looks like the link to the docs is broken, could you please update it?

Comment: @GiorgioBalestrieri: Done. Thanks for the notification.